# How to set up a data flow from nodejs backend to polymer front end

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, polymer

I just have a general question, is there a known way to do that :
On my back-end I have a little piece of code that get data every XXX milisecond from a sensor connected to my raspberry pi and i would like to send this data to a UI element that display it ? Is there a common/well known way to setup this kind of data flow ?
(I'd like to avoid using a database it seems a heavy solution)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions using depending on if you only need the latest data (1) or if you want to push and record all data values upon starting the front-end application (2):

1) Your front-end could query the back-end using an ajax request every n seconds. Upon loading your front-end application you could call a function that looks as follows:

```
function runForever() {
     getValueAndUpdateUI(); // AJAX request and UI update performed here
     setTimeout(runForever, 1000); // Call runForever after 1 second
}
```

2) Use websockets to push data to the front-end as the values come in (increases complexity).

Comment: Then it seems that Ajax is one good solution to my problem :). Thank you  for your time and good answer